# Nesting flexbox layout causes scrollable area to misbehave

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've read various questions about scrolling within flexbox but I seem to have a slightly more complicated version of what I've seen.  I have an editor that uses flexbox and contains a toolbar with many components that is scrollable, and this works fine on its own.  However, on the live site it's wrapped in a parent which is `display:flex` (for reasons I won't go into but this editor isn't the only component on the page), and as soon as the editor is put within this flex parent its scrollable area becomes full width, pushing the whole page wider than it should be.

In this snippet, all the 'Thumb Example' elements are supposed to be scrollable within their parent `.image-thumbs-container` respecting the page's overall `width:800px` limit, but they lay out and push their parent wider than that.  But, if you turn off the `display:flex` of the `.product-page` element, the scrolling then works.  I built this simplified example of just the editor to demonstrate the problem, and it worked fine, took me a while to realise it was a parent element that was causing the error.

[Edit] This snippet may not work as expected within StackOverflow, please see this identical Pen: https://codepen.io/neekfenwick/pen/NWbpqZg

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.page-container {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: white;
}

.product-page {
    display: flex; /* Disable me to make scrolling work */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.uploads-container {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.uploads-scroller {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.image-thumbs-container {
    border: initial;
}
.image-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mock.css">
    <title>Mockup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="product-page">
            <div class="unrelated-content">Page contains other content required to layout by flexbox.</div>

            <div class="editor">
                <div class="uploads-panel">
                    <div class="uploads-container">
                        <div class="uploads-file-container">File Upload<br>Widget Goes<br>Here</div>
                        <div class="uploads-scroller">
                            <div class="image-thumbs-container">
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="workspace">
                    <h2>Some complicated workspace content goes here.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="unrelated-content">Page contains other content required to layout by flexbox.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, please bear in mind I don't want to alter anything above the `.editor` div.  A lot of our site relies on the `.product-page` CSS.  I can consider it, but, is it possible to fix this scrolling problem by only modifying elements from the `.editor` div and down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this one by just setting 100% width on `.editor`.

Since the parent already has `flex-wrap: wrap`, this should work out just fine for you. The content below the editor will just wrap to below it.

```css
.editor { /* <-- add this */
  width: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.page-container {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: white;
}

.product-page {
    display: flex; /* Disable me to make scrolling work */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.uploads-container {
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.uploads-scroller {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.image-thumbs-container {
    border: initial;
}
.image-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 2px grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mock.css">
    <title>Mockup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="product-page">
            <div class="unrelated-content">Page contains other content required to layout by flexbox.</div>

            <div class="editor">
                <div class="uploads-panel">
                    <div class="uploads-container">
                        <div class="uploads-file-container">File Upload<br>Widget Goes<br>Here</div>
                        <div class="uploads-scroller">
                            <div class="image-thumbs-container">
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                                <div class="image-thumb">Thumb<br>Example</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="workspace">
                    <h2>Some complicated workspace content goes here.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="unrelated-content">Page contains other content required to layout by flexbox.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that does solve it.  I actually had multiple parents with `display: flex` so I had to set `width: 100%` in two places, but it was all within the context of this editor's container and did not have to mess with the `.product-layout` level of the, so it's all good.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Add `width: 100%` to your .editor element.

Or, just in case you really needed to, add `max-width: 800px` to any of the following elements... *.editor*, *.uploads-container*, or *.uploads-container*

Comment: Thank you @BradTheBluefish .. @cjl750 got there a little before you so I've Accepted their answer, but yours is also on the money.  Obviously setting child elements to a fixed width isn't preferred when everything's supposed to inherit width from the topmost page layout level, but the `width: 100%` trick worked.  Now I just have to figure out why it worked :)